# R BootStrap Data Frame

Tags: r, statistics-bootstrap

```
# Bootstrap 95% CI for R-Squared
library(boot)
# function to obtain R-Squared from the data
rsq <- function(formula, data, indices) {
  d <- data[indices,] # allows boot to select sample
  fit <- lm(formula, data=d)
  return(coef(fit))
}
# bootstrapping with 1000 replications
results <- boot(data=mtcars, statistic=rsq,
   R=1000, formula=mpg~wt+disp)

# get 95% confidence interval
boot.ci(results, type="bca")
```

Say you run this bootstrap and get 1000 estimates of the intercept, wt and disp variables and so then you want to put all estimates into the data frame.

```
dataframe = data.frame(results$t)
```

That will do it but how do you code it to make sure that the column names get the right variable names? I did it that way and it makes column names 'Var1' 'Var2' and 'Var3' but I would wish for them to be 'Intercept' 'wt' and 'weight' and I know I can change them to this; I am wondering how to automate it to make sure the columns get the right names from boot.

Comment: You may need `names(dataframe) <- names(results$t0)`

Comment: Based on the function you have, the `t` is a matrix with no names attribute, while `t0` i.e. the one returned from 'rsq` have the `names` and you can assign the names based on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, we can make use of the `names` attribute from the 't0' component.  When we have model objects (or any objects), it is better to check `str` to understand the structure of each of the components.  This would help greatly in understanding the models and the components

```
str(results)
#List of 11
# $ t0       : Named num [1:3] 34.9606 -3.3508 -0.0177
#  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "(Intercept)" "wt" "disp"
# $ t        : num [1:1000, 1:3] 34.1 37.2 37.3 33.8 34.7 ...
# $ R        : num 1000
# ...
```

The output is a `list` and extracting the `list` components can be done with `$` or `[[` (for multiple elements, `[`)

The `t` element is a `matrix` with no `dimnames` attribute while `t0` have the "names" attribute.  So, if we want to rename the `data.frame` converted `matrix`, just extract the `names`

```
df1 <- data.frame(results$t)
names(df1) <- names(results$t0)
```